# How do I retrieve all recipes using a particular ingredient in Cakephp 2.0?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have 2 models which are connected via a HABTM association, in the same way that Recipes and Ingredients are associated in the cookbook.

I need to do the equivalent of finding all recipes which use a particular ingredient - how do I do that?

So basically, I'll have ingredient_id, and I want to do something like:

```
$this->Recipe->find('all', array('conditions' => 'recipe uses this ingredient'));
```

I'd also like to retrieve a list of all ingredients which are used in at least one recipe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use HABTM (`hasAndBelongsToMany`) relationships in CakePHP, it creates a model by combining the names of both models in alphabetical order ([reference](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#hasandbelongstomany-habtm)). You can use that model to perform your query.

**Example:**

```
<?php

$recipes = $this->Recipe->IngredientsRecipe->find('all', array(
    'conditions' => array(
        'IngredientsRecipe.ingredient_id' => 1 // This could also be an array of ingredients
    ),
    'group' => array('Recipe.id')
));
```

In the example above, we're using the IngredientsRecipe model which has 2 relationships, both `belongsTo` with Ingredient and Recipe. Just in case a Recipe has multiple ingredients that match, we're also grouping by the recipe ID.

**PS:** You don't need to define the relationship to IngredientsRecipe as long as you've defined the hasAndBelongsToMany relationship between Recipe and Ingredients. CakePHP will do the rest automatically.

Comment: @Sharon - One thing I should point out about the answer left by @jeremyharris is that you'd be performing 2x as many queries.  The `getRecipesFromIngredients` function he suggested placing in your model already returns all of what you need and yet he suggests that you then query for the exact same data again in the controller using the list of `recipe_id` extracted from the result of the previous queries.

Answer (score 2):

There's no easy way to do it, but it can be accomplished several different ways. Here's probably the easiest: define a function that pulls a list of recipe id's from the join table and then search on that.

So, on the Ingredient model:

```
function getRecipesFromIngredients($ingredient_ids) {
  // IngredientsRecipe is the automatically created model
  // Use what you defined in the 'with' key on your HABTM 
  // definition if you defined a 'with' key
  $results = $this->IngredientsRecipe->find('all', array(
    'conditions' => array(
      'ingredient_id' => $ingredient_ids
    ),
  ));
  return Set::extract('/IngredientsRecipe/recipe_id', $results);
}
```

This becomes a very testable, reusable function.

Then in the recipes controller:

```
// would pull all recipes that have ingredients 1 and 2
$recipes = $this->Recipe->find('all', array(
  'conditions' => array(
    'id' => $this->Recipe->Ingredient->getRecipesFromIngredients(array(1,2))
  )
));
```